# How to center a left-aligned image on mobile?

Tags: css, image, mobile

The image on my home page is left aligned.

While [it looks great on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HomV.jpg), it [does not look good on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JepG7.jpg)

I am trying to "center" the image defined by `.entry-image.attachment-post.gsfc-alignleft` on mobile views.

I have tried the following without success :

```
@media all and (max-width: 675px) {

.entry-image.attachment-post.gsfc-alignleft {

   width: 100%!important;
   max-width: none;
   text-align: center;
   margin-left: auto!important;
   margin-right: auto!important;
  }
}
```

My website is : parlons-survivalisme.com

What am I missing ?

Comment: There is not enough code here to help. Your style should stretch the image to 100% of its offset parent, but you haven't provided any markup to show us what the page layout looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the outer `a` Tag to `width: 100%` in order to align the image above the whole width.

For instance:

```
a.alignleft {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As advised by Luca, changed the code to the following, which works !!

```
@media all and (max-width: 675px) {

a.alignleft {
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   text-align: center;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 straightforward solutions to center an image.
The first is to set your image to 'display: inline-block' and then wrap it with an outer div where you set the 'text-align' property to center.

```
.wrapper-div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center
} 
.img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The other solution is to make sure your img is a block element (display: block) and then set the margin-right and margin-left to auto.

```
.img {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

If you still have a bug, look at the parent element width (to make sure it is 100% on small screens).